# How to use Java 8 features to generate collection?

Tags: java, collections, java-8

If I have a class `Book` that has inside it a List of `Page` objects, how can I generate a collection of objects of `Page` given a collection of `Book` objects, using Java 8 features such as Streams, Collectors, lamdas etc.? I know how to do this using pre-Java 8 techniques, but I would like to see it done with one line with the Java 8 features.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that a `Book` has a `getPages` method returning a collection of `Page`s, you need to use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) method to "flatten" collections of pages inside a collection of books:

```
Stream<Page> pages = books.stream().flatMap(b -> b.getPages().stream());
```

This produces a stream; if you need a collection, use list collector to construct it.

Comment: This worked great, flatMap was the missing ingredient. I was hitting a dead end with forEach on the Books. Thanks for a constructive answer.